# NameError: name 're' is not defined

Tags: python

I am very new to python. Very new. I copied the following from a tutorial

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

webpage = urlopen('http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/LatestNews').read

patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')

patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel.*href="(.*)"/>')

findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle,webpage)

findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink,webpage)

listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(2,16)

for i in listIterator:
    print findPatTitle[i]
    print findPatLink[i]
    print "\n"
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which tutorial did you copy this from? It is littered with errors.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap_DlSrT-iE&feature=related

Comment: Then you should compare your code with the accompanying code here: http://www.newthinktank.com/2010/11/python-2-7-tutorial-pt-13-website-scraping/ . After a little tidy-up I've found that it works.

Comment: I rolled back your edit to the question because chameleon questions are not acceptable. You can't just invalidate the efforts of the people who posted answers to your original question like that.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to import [regular expression module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) in your code

```
import re
re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
```

Comment: thanks. I now get another error..please see my edits

Comment: @user522962 `webpage = urlopen('http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/LatestNews').read` should be `webpage = urlopen('http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/LatestNews').read()`

Answer (score 2):

As well as the missing `import re`, your program has another error. In

```
webpage = urlopen('http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/LatestNews').read
```

You left the `()` off after `read` at the end of the line. So currently `webpage` is a reference to the `.read` method, it's not the result of the `.read()` call.